# No longer receiving newsletters

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, newsletter

I am signed up for many Stack Exchange newsletters according to [my profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1677570/ferrybig?tab=subscriptions), but these emails stopped arriving in my mail since Thursday.

The last email that has arrived is dated Wednesday, February 24, 2016 and since then I no longer receive mail. I have check my spam box and added Stack Exchange to my contact list, but it didn't resolve the issue last Friday, because they also stopped arriving.

*With newsletter I mean the [weekly site specific newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters).*

<s>**Edit:** I notice that the preview for the newsletter from at least StackOverflow is blank, is this the cause of the bug?</s>

Comment: I get newsletters on Monday, Tuesday, and Thursday, and I also did not get one this Thursday (the 25th).  No blank previews though.

Comment: Are you browsing the page using https? I am getting mixed content warnings on the network tab, so the preview doesn't seem to load. Should be fine if you browse using http.

Comment: Preview problem is indeed caused by the http vs https problem. Still didn't receive my newsletters for last thursday and friday (many sites)

Comment: I can confirm that we don't seem to have sent out any newsletters since the 24th. Looking into what the underlying issue is.

Comment: Also - thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, a change introduced on the 24th meant that our scheduler didn't hit the "send newsletter" schedule.

I've fixed that and newsletters should start flowing from 18:00GMT today (that is, about 5 and a half hours from when this is posted).

Comment: Maybe worth adding an alert sent to someone in the team, e.g. if no newsletters are sent for X hours, in case such thing happens again?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - most of us do have subscriptions, but not as many as the OP, so we _would_ have noticed. But yes, point taken.

Comment: Verified, all 8 newsletters I have subscribed to have been received for Monday 29th (for the people wondering, yes I am subscribed to 37 newsletters)